# Read Resource strings programmatically

Tags: c#

I Have around say 6 dll's ( No source code ).
They do not contain any Logic but just a .resx file that contains a string table.

Is there a way where I can extract the Id's and values from the string table from each of these dll's and Export it to a text file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowing the assembly name and the resource file, you can load it using reflection.

```
// Resources dll
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ResourcesLib.DLL");

// Resource file.. namespace.ClassName
var rm = new ResourceManager("ResourcesLib.Messages", assembly);

// Now you can get the values
var x = rm.GetString("Hi");
```

To list all Keys and Values you can use the `ResourceSet`

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ResourcesLib.DLL");
var rm = new ResourceManager("ResourcesLib.Messages", assembly);

var rs = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

foreach (DictionaryEntry r in rs)
{
    var key = r.Key.ToString();
    var val = r.Value.ToString();
}
```

If you don't have access to the resources lib, you can see what are the namespaces, classes, and everything else through [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) as mentioned by Leo.

Comment: yeah, doesn`t need to be dynamic hehehe, but one day i will found something that it fits hehehe, by the way.... this solution should works

Comment: Yes, It does List the resources in  rm, But I do not know the Ids in the string table. So How do i use it in GetString?

Comment: I need to list the Ids and the value !

Comment: @Maneesh: Updated to list all resources.