# Localization in MEF: export attribute does not support a resource (WPF - C#)

Tags: wpf, plugins, localization, mef

I have an application with a plugin architecture using MEF. For every exported part there is an attribute with the part's name, and I want to have the names translated, because I use these strings to display the available parts in ListBoxes (or the like).

So, I tried to set the 'Name = Strings.SomeText" in the [Export] annotation, but I get the following error:

"An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

Is there a solution to this? I find the use of the Metadata very useful (I do lazy loading) and I would not want to redesign everything just to get a few texts translated.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: FYI: I just found out that MEF 2 supports exactly the generic import I was looking for, but you'll have to target .NET Framework 4.5 to take advantage of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't directly provide the translated text to the attributes because an attribute can only contain data that is known at [compile time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). So you will need to provide some compile time constant value that you can later use to look up the translated test.

One solution would be to pass the resource name to the attribute. Then when you want to display the translated text you grab the resource name, look up the text in the resources and display the result.

For instance your attribute could look something like:

```
[Export(Name = "SomeText")]
public class MyExport
{
}
```

Then when you want to display the string you load the resources from the assembly that defines the export and you extract the actual text from the loaded resources. For instance like this (as borrowed from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827643/539846)):

```
var assembly = typeof(MyExport).Assembly;

// Resource file.. namespace.ClassName
var rm = new ResourceManager("MyAssembly.Strings", assembly);

// exportName contains the text provided to the Name property 
// of the Export attribute
var text = rm.GetString(exportName);
```

The one obvious drawback about this solution is that you lose the type-safety that you get from using the Strings.SomeText property.

--------- EDIT ---------

In order to make it a little easier to get the translated text you could create a derivative of the `ExportAttribute` which takes enough information to extract the translated text. For example the custom `ExportAttribute` could look like this

```
public sealed class NamedExportAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public NamedExportAttribute()
        : base()
    { 
    }

    public string ResourceName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Type ResourceType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ResourceText()
    {
        var rm = new ResourceManager(ResourceType);
        return rm.GetString(ResourceName);
    }
}
```

Using this attribute you can apply it like this

```
[NamedExport(
    ResourceName = "SomeText", 
    ResourceType = typeof(MyNamespace.Properties.Resources))]
public sealed class MyClass
{ 
}
```

Finally when you need to get the translated text you can do this

```
var attribute = typeof(MyClass).GetCustomAttribute<NamedExportAttribute>();
var text = attribute.ResourceText();
```

Another option is to use the [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Petrik for taking time to answer. I had no real hope to find a good alternative, and in my case your answer is more complicated to implement (for other, unrelated reasons). Anyway, I'm marking it as answer, regards,

Comment: Have you defined your own ExportAttribute derivative class? If so then you could potentially bundle all the code necessary to load the resources in there.

Comment: Indeed, I have my own ExportAttribute, but I don't see clearly how to apply your solution there. Do you have an example? Thanks

Comment: I've added the example. Note that there are probably nicer ways of getting the data. Also I haven't added any exception handling etc.

Comment: Thank you again, Petrik! Very nice example. I found out that MEF 2 implements generic imports (see my comment to the original question). Regards!

Comment: By the way, I got this to work with some adaptation, because I could not get these lines to work: 
var attribute = typeof(MyClass).GetCustomAttribute<NamedExportAttribute>();
var text = attribute.ResourceText();

The "GetCustomAttribute" method is not part of System.Type, maybe I'm missing a "using" with some extension. Anyway, if someone needs to know my solution please let me know.